# Is this a bad question?

Tags: discussion, specific-question

I asked [my first question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35544771/how-to-implement-a-listener-for-a-final-method-of-an-instance-in-java) "How to implement a listener for a final method of an instance in Java" the other day.

I somewhat expected the answers to essentially be "*you can't* (implement a listener for a final method)" or a long complicated hack that nobody really wants to recommend to anyone. But instead, they are essentially "you can't override a final method". I was aware of this when writing up the question, and even included it in my opening statement.

I thought the reason why I didn't get too much traffic might have been because of the timing of the post (I'm in Japan). But I thought the [java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java) tag would have enough traffic anyways.

Then I got upvoted once, downvoted once (no comment) and that's it so far. I'm thinking this question might end up granting me the tumbleweed badge.

Should I wait longer? Should I post a bounty (I wouldn't want to do that if the answer is a one-liner)? Should I make the premise more clear? Is the question too broad? Too localized? What am I missing? Any help, criticism or even nitpicking is appreciated.

Comment: To be fair, you ask "How to implement a listener for a final method of an instance in Java" then waste time explaining that you know it can't be done. The answers say it cannot be done. What you really mean to ask is: "How can I implement a listener in java without final override" at least then you immediately lead the answer away from the obvious.

Comment: @MeirionHughes yeah, I guess it would be much more straightforward to just rephrase it like that. Then again, the answer I was hoping for was with or without override (maybe there is a hack).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The question looks alright to me, and the answers make sense.    It *might* be indicative of an [XY problem](http://xyproblem.info/), but your premise is clean enough that I'm comfortably sure that it isn't.

I'm not sure what you're looking to get out of adding a bounty to it; if adding a listener in the way you desire means that you have to extend it, and the class is `final`, then the answer is accurate.

So no, it's not a bad question.  You're probably not getting the answer you want, but there's nothing inherently wrong with it that I can see.